# hg clone "Authorization failed" on subrepository hosted on bitbucket

Tags: authentication, mercurial, bitbucket

Tested in SourceTree & TortoiseHg

I have a repository

```
Main
```

and a subrepository

```
Sub
```

And cloning works for me, but every time my friend tries to clone it fails with an authentication failure.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change

**.hgsub**

```
nested = https://<user>@bitbucket.org/user/repo
```

to

```
nested = https://bitbucket.org/user/repo
```